# Delete rows with null values

Tags: pyspark

I have a data set with 15 variables. All the variables have empty values in it. I want to delete the rows from the data set even if it has one empty observation in it.

can u guys help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Easy, I guess you could've sorted it out searching on google:

```
df.dropna()
```